# Add constant values to a column in a table - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I wish to add into a table the values of x2 and y2. As both x2 and y2 have a constant values I just wrote x2 value 10 times. Is there a short way to do so which can also be applied on y2 value column?

code:

```
clc;
clear all;
x1 = [38;43;38;40;49;18;41;58;10;55];
y1 =rot90(11:20);

x2 =[2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2];
y2 =6;
 
dTable = table(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

Comment: Check [repmat](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

Comment: BTW, "constant" is probably the wrong term here; I think you mean 'scalar". It's the size/shape of the variable that's affecting you here, not whether it's initialized from a literal or if its mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `repmat`

```
x1 = [38;43;38;40;49;18;41;58;10;55];
x2 = repmat( 2, 10, 1 ); % 10 rows, 1 column
dTable = table(x1,x2);
```

Or if you have an existing table, you can assign a constant to an entire column like so

```
x1 = [38;43;38;40;49;18;41;58;10;55];
dTable = table(x1);
dTable.x2(:) = 2; % Assign all rows of column "x2" to the value 2
```

Comment: Slightly more dynamic: `x2 = repmat(2, size(x1));` Gets the hardcoded constant out of your code.